# Bash script to grep through one file for a list names, then grep through a second file to match those names to get a lookup value

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Somehow, being specific just doesn't translate well into a title.

Here is my goal, using BASH script in a cygwin environment:

1. Read text file $filename to get a list of schemas and table names
2. Take that list of schemas and table names and find a match in $lookup_file to get a value
3. Use that value to make a logic choice

I basically have each item working separately. I just can't figure out how to glue it all together.

For step one, it's

```
grep $search_string $filename | awk '{print $1, $5}' | sed -e 's~"~~g' -e 's~ ~\t~g'
```

Which gives a list of schema{tab}table

For step two, it's

```
grep -e '{}' $lookup_file | awk '{print $3}'
```

Where $lookup_file is schema{tab}table{tab}value

Step three is basically, based on the value returned, do "something"; file a report, email a warning, ignore it, etc.

I tried stringing part one and two together with xargs, but it treats the schema and the table name as filenames and throws errors.

What is the glue I'm missing? Or is there a better method?

Comment: `awk` can do its own grepping, you don't need to pipe `grep` to it. And it can also do its own replacing, you don't need to pipe it to sed.

Comment: Please do not forget to quote filenames. Like ``grep "$search_string" "$filename"`` and ``grep -e '{}' "$lookup_file"``

Comment: I actually could think of a solution but I'm curious how data between `""` are placed. Could they contain spaces or not? How about the other fields? Are they placed around `""` too? Are they separated by spaces or tabs?

Comment: Since people are asking, here is an example line from the $filename; `schema{space}-{space}text{space}search_string{space}"table"`. Note only the table name is surrounded by quotes. The text will not contain any extra spaces to worry about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v s="$search_string" 'NR == FNR { if ($0 ~ s) { gsub(/"/, "", $5); a[$1, $5] = 1; }; next; } a[$1, $2] { print $3; }' "$filename" "$lookup_file"
```

Explained:

`NR == FNR { if ($0 ~ s) { gsub(/"/, "", $5); a[$1, $5] = 1; }; next; }` targets the first file, searching for valid matches on it, and save key values in array `a`.

`a[$1, $2] { print $3; }` targets the second file and prints the value in its third column if it finds matches with the first and second column of the file and the keys in array `a`.

Comment: @MivaScott My code above should have worked for you already even though the step `gsub(/"/, "", $1);` is no longer necessary and could be removed.

Comment: This is the answer I'm going to have to go with. A little more cryptic than I'd hope for but I can't have everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v search="$search_string" '$0 ~ search { gsub(/"/, "", $5);
                                              print $1"\t"$5; }' "$filename" |
    while read line
    do
        result=$(awk -v search="\b$line\b" '$0 ~ search { print $3; } ' "$lookup_file");
        # Do "something" with $result
    done
```

Comment: Probably easier to use `/"/` than `"\""`

Comment: This is very close except for how the first awk outputs the name. And I can see where it went astray. When I used sed to remove the {space} character, it was not because any of the data has spaces; it was a byproduct of awk putting a space in between column 1 and 5. So the gsub's to remove the space can be removed, and only the last column has quotes so I cut out the gsub for column 1. But I still cannot figure out how to change the awk print command to use a tab instead of a space. Hopefully once past that hurdle it should be perfect.

Comment: Edited to put a TAB between the columns.

Comment: Awesome.. Last wrinkle. The search is finding extra table names. So if there is a `table_a` in the list, when it does a look up it will give the results for `table_a`, `table_apple`, and `table_america` for example. I've found a few examples of doing an exact match, but I either get errors or no results. How can I make sure `$line` is JUST `/$line/`?

Comment: I added `\b` to the regular expression to match word boundaries.

Comment: Are the schema and table names in specific columns of the lookup file? Instead of using regular expression matching, you could use something like `$1 == schema && $2 == table`.

Comment: I tried entering the \b's but I still didn't get results. Thank you for your help. I'll keep playing with it, but for now I'm going to go with the other answer.